How to Integrate Microsoft's Debug Adapter Protocol (DAP) with the Monaco Editor?
I am currently working on adding a debugger option to my code editor without using an IDE. In my research, I came across Microsoft's Debug Adapter Protocol (DAP), and I've read through the documentation, which mentions that it can be integrated into IDEs or editors. I would like to know if DAP is compatible with the Monaco editor and how to connect them.
I attempted to download javascript debugger, which is a DAP implementation, via npm install. I found that it is also available as an extension for VS Code. I installed javascript debugger through npm, but I am unsure how to proceed with integrating it into the Monaco editor. I was expecting to find clear instructions or examples on how to set up DAP with Monaco, but I haven't been successful.
Could someone please guide me on the steps and processes involved in achieving this integration? Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
